# From Visual Studio Code, can I have Git use a different merge tool (defined in .gitconfig)?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge

I would like VS Code to follow my .gitconfig for using a different merge tool (not VS Code) however I see that when I do a Merge and have conflicts, the only option seems to be to open and resolve that conflict within VS Code's own editor.
I would like for it to run the command I have defined in my .gitconfig (which currently points to KDiff) instead.

Is there a way to have VS Code use the .gitconfig defined Merge tool when I choose to resolve the conflict from the 'Merge Changes' section in VS Code?

(Note: My .gitconfig works fine, as I've found if I run the Merge from something like GitExtensions, my external merge tool (KDiff) runs correctly).

Comment: Do you have a git bash installed on your system? If yes then I might have an answer for you

Comment: Yes I do, but was hoping this would just be a setting in VSCode to say 'don't do your own thing, follow the source control provider's settings'.